# How to added an automatic image slide show that does not clash with the update content function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have some images that I am displaying through JSON. This file refreshes the content every 10 seconds so the new images added show without a page refresh.

I am struggling to add a slideshow code without the two refresh's clashing with each other.

I would really appreciate some help.

This is my current code.

```js
function update_content() {
    $.getJSON("showImages.php", function(data) {
        $("#slides").html(
            data.result.map(({image1}) => `<img class="slides" src="data:image/png;base64,${image1}" />`).join("")
        );
        setTimeout(update_content, 10000); 
        
        var index = 0;
        slideshow();
        function slideshow() {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            
            index++;
            if (index > x.length) {index = 1}    
            x[index-1].style.display = "block";  
            setTimeout(slideshow, 20000); 
        }
        
    })
}
$(function() {
    update_content()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written, there's no way the refreshes wouldn't clash with each other and cause a large mess in updating. What you have here will, every 10 seconds, do a ping back to the server for some json and then spawn what is essentially a thread (not in the technical sense, but in the behavior sense) that every 20 seconds hides all the slides and shows the first slide. By about 60 seconds into this page running, you now have six instances of the `slideshow()` function queued to run, the newly created one trying to show the first slide, the next most recently created two showing the second, the next two showing the third, etc. And because network lag is unpredictable, they'll all fire at slightly different times in an unpredictable order.

The main problem is `setTimeout(slideshow, 20000)`. It's not needed as this is currently written. Slideshow() is being run every 10 seconds already from the outer function running every 10; it doesn't need to run separately in its own timeout. And if you're running it at that interval already, the slideshow function is useless anyway, and the server only needs to return one image in its json, and the whole slideshow function can be deleted.

Though I question why you need to do a network round-trip every 10 seconds to begin with. Unless this is some real-time snapshot of a camera feed or something, you can easily just give javascript a large array of images for it to cycle through and maybe do the server ping for new images every 10 minutes or so instead. If you go this route, instead move `slideshow()` out of the `update_content()` function and just call it once from the jquery onready function to set it running and leave it be. If you need to call `slideshow()` in the `getJson` callback, be sure to `cancelTimeout` on the previous `setTimeout(slideshow, ...)`'s return value, so you don't make pseudo-threads as described above.

Comment: I have a page that displays the images in a slideshow format. What I want to do is when I upload an image to the MySQL database it pulls that through and displays it on the page preferably straight away. The 10 mins server ping is my last resort. Would there be another way? if so any chance you can show me an example please as I am a bit lost if I am honest.

I have a similar code for texts which runs through a marquee and that updates instantly without effecting the scroll. I would love to do the same for the images slideshow.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you wanted a new image to be displayed immediately, hitting your server with a ping every ten seconds is a good way to quickly DOS yourself if/when the user base grows in scale. I would suggest looking into websockets if that's a concern, so the server can send the connected clients a notification about a new image. (This is a "poll vs push" problem.) -- If you're not worried about scaling up, then what I said in my second paragraph would apply: merge the slideshow into the function that pings the server. The main problem is the multiple "threads" stomping on each other.